# Extract two columns from a column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which contains strings in this format

```
Rondonópolis (c/ 5,2%) 3500 7000 2789 4258
```

I need to create two columns and stay that way. I've been trying to use regex but I still can't

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Rondonópolis (c/ 5,2%) | 3500 7000 2789 4258 |

Comment: You could also do it the lazy way: `.split(')')` then fix the leftmost string (add the ')' back).

Comment: @coelho For example this worked. But I have other strings in this format ```Ponta Grossa 2100 3121 4578 3234``` who returned ```NaN```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.extract` to extract two groups: one of the numbers (four 4-digit numbers) and the other everything preceding those numbers.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_column': ["Rondonópolis (c/ 5,2%) 3500 7000 2789 4258", "Ponta Grossa 2100 3121 4578 3234"]})
df[['A', 'B']] = df['my_column'].str.extract(r"(.+) (\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4})")
```

[image: res]